# Facebook permissions & graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-permissions

I have created an application on Facebook Developers, with permissions `email` and `users_like`.

When a use graph api explorer tool choosing my application token I can't read user email.( email property appear in gray )

I don't know what is wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

> created an application on Facebook Developers, with permissions email and users_like

You have to add the permissions while login/authentication - after that only you'll get the access token with the power to get these fields.

To do it using the Graph API Explorer, click on the button **Get Access Token**; then check the permissions you required and then submit your call.

Good luck!